# attach the red title to the top of the border

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a red title as a red headline that 1-I need to mount and attach it to the frame, I need to Push up the title to the red border.2 - I want to move the middle column to the center between right for the left column with equal spacing between them.I can not do this and I do not know why. Thankas.
see example:[see example:](http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide.htm#)

css dode:

```
a { color:blue; }
#content { background-color:#dddddd; width:200px; margin-top:2px; }

html{
    height:0px;
    text-align: right;
    width:1280;
    height:1024px;

}


body {
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_body.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    font-family:Palatino Linotype;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px ;
    padding: 0px ;
    height:1200px;

}
#thirdLine{
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_lineYellow.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;   
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    line-height: 7px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #745B1B;
    font-family: 'CarterOneRegular';
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #FFF0D8;
    width: auto;
}
#wrapMein, #LeftColumn, #columnmiddle, #rightcolumn {
    height:800px;

}
#wrapMein{
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_wrapMein.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    margin: 0px 5px 20px 5px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    vertical-align: top;
     clear:both;
     height:1200px;
}
#columnmiddleTitle{
vertical-align: top;
}
#LeftColumn, #columnmiddle{
 float: left;
}

#LeftColumn {
    position: relative;
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_lineYellow.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    width: 25%;
}
#leftcolumn_s {
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_line.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;   
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 1px 1px 1px;
    height: 115px;
    margin: 0 auto ;
    padding: 10px;
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0px;
    width: 240px;   
}

#columnmiddle{
    position: relative;

    border-color: red;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;  
    margin: 5px auto;

    padding: opx 10px opx 10px;
    width:40%;


}
#lineAzure {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #880000;
    line-height: 11px;
    margin: 0;
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
}

#insidWindow {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_inside_window.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;  
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 730px;
    width:95%;

}


#rightcolumn {
    position: relative;
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_lineYellow.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    margin: 5px ;
    padding: 0 5px ;
    width: 30%;
    float:right;
    }
    #rightcolumn_s{
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_line.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;   
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 1px 1px 1px;
    height: 115px;
    padding: 10px ;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:90%;
 }


h2 {


    color: #443333;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 7px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
}
.secondLine{
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_line.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;   
    line-height: 7px;
    margin: 0px ;
    height:15px;
}
#lineAzurebotom {
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0px; 
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #880000;
    line-height: 11px;
    font-family: 'CarterOneRegular';
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #FFF0D8;
    width: 100%;
}



#chatRead {
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_dark.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 1px 1px 1px;
    line-height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    height:290px;
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:80px; 

}
#chatWrite {
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_line.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;   
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 1px 1px 1px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:40px; 
}




.rcolumn{
    position:relative;
    background-image:url('http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/bacround_lineYellow.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    width:25%;
    height:495px;
    float:right;
    color: red;
}
.ui-wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #70A029;
}

.ui-resizable {
    position: relative;
}

.ui-resizable-e {
    background: url("../pic/resizable-e.gif") repeat scroll right center transparent;
    cursor: e-resize;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 6px;
}
.ui-resizable-handle {
    display: none;
    font-size: 0.1px;
    position: absolute;
}
.ui-resizable-s {
    background: url("../pic/resizable-s.gif") repeat scroll center top transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: s-resize;
    height: 6px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.ui-resizable-se {
    background: url("../pic/resizable-se.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: se-resize;
    height: 9px;
    right: 0;
    width: 9px;
}
.maintitle1 {
    background: center top #2C6987 repeat-x scroll ;
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #528CBC inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;

}
#logo{
    border-color: #316897;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    float:left;
    height: 97%;

}
.resolution span {
    color: #2B8E00;
    display: block;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

html code:

```
<body >



<h2>this is body background.</h2>



<div class="secondLine">this is div class secondLine </div>

<div id="thirdLine"><img id="logo" src="http://www.centerwow.com/linkguide/guide_files/pic/Notebook.png" alt="Link Guide"  />this is div id  thirdLine</div>

<div id="wrapMein">



    <div id="LeftColumn" >here is div id = LeftColumn

                <div id="leftcolumn_s">here is div id = leftcolumn_s</div>

            </div>

    <div id="columnmiddle">

            <!--<div id="lineAzure" >this div class lineAzure spnbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</div>-->    

                <div id="columnmiddleTitle"><H3 class="maintitle1" style="color:red">RED TITLE</H3></div>

                <div id="insidWindow">insidWindow

                    <div id="windowResize" class="ui-wrapper" style="height: 340px; width: 350px;">

                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; ">

                            Resize me<br>

                            Please try to resizeme:<br> www www www.

                            <div class="resolution">

                                You are using

                                <span id="resolutionNumber"></span>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div><br>

                </div><!--insidWindow-->



            </div><!--columnmiddle-->   

        <div id="rightcolumn" >div id="rightcolumn" 

                <div class="floatRight"><H3 class="maintitle1">articals</H3></div>

                    <ul style="float: right;" dir="rtl" >

                  <li>

                    <a href="#" onclick="toggle('node1')">Item 1</a>

                    <ul id="node1" style="display:none">

                      <li>Sub-item 1</li>

                      <li>

                        <a href="#" onclick="toggle('node2')">Sub-item 2</a>

                        <ul id="node2" style="display:none">

                          <li>Sub-sub-item 1</li>

                          <li>Sub-sub-item 2</li>

                        </ul>

                      </li>

                      <li>Sub-item 3</li>

                    </ul>

                  </li>

                  <li>

                    <a href="#" onclick="toggle('node3')">Item 2</a>

                    <ul id="node3" style="display:none">

                      <li>Sub-item 1</li>

                      <li>Sub-item 2</li>

                    </ul>

                  </li>

                  <li>Item 3</li>

                </ul>

                <div id="rightcolumn_s">here is div id = rightcolumn_s</div>

            </div>





        <div id="chatRead">here is div id = chatread</div>

                <div id="chatWrite">here is div id = chatWrite</div>

        <div id="lineAzurebotom">here is div id = lineAzurebotom</div>

</div><!--wrapMein-->



</body>
```

Comment: just add **margin:0px !important** css style `maintitle1` class

Answer (score 1):

Solution for question 1:

```
#maintitle1 {
 margin: 0; /* added */
}
```

Solution for question 2:

```
#columnmiddle { 
 margin-left: 0.5%; /* instead of auto */
}
```

Notice that the solution for question 2 is a bit of a hack. The issue that you are having is that the widths of leftcolumn, centercolumn and rightcolumn not add up to 100%. Since right column is floated right and leftcolumn and centercolumn are floated left, you end up with the left-over space between centercolumn and rightcolumn. I looked at the size of this space and added half of it as a left margin to centercolumn. This solution works but isn't very beautiful in my opinion. Alternatively you have to make all three column float left and make sure their widths add up to 100%. For example like this:

```
#columnleft, #columnmiddle, #columnright { 
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#columnmiddle { 
 width: 60%;
}

#columnleft, #columnright { 
 width: 20%;
}
```